# Android - Using thread

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have three class in my app.
First extends Activity

```
public class TestProjActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
String my ="";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Translation th = new Translation(this);
            my = th.doSomeJob();
            }
    }).start();
    Log.d("ONCREATE", my);  
}
```

}

Second is DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper {
private final Context myContext;

public DBHelper(Context context) {      
    this.myContext = context;       
}
```

}

and third one extends DBhelper

```
public class Translation extends DBHelper {


public Translation(Runnable runnable) {
    super((Context) runnable);          
    }

public String doSomeJob(){
    return "Yes I DID!";
}
```

}

future I will change this classes to do real job but now,
 when I run this I get this error:

- 05-11 13:15:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(512): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-8 exiting due to uncaught exception
- 05-11 13:15:53.028: E/AndroidRuntime(512): java.lang.ClassCastException: iKA.PROJ.TestProjActivity$1
- 05-11 13:15:53.028: E/AndroidRuntime(512):   at another.pack.Translation.(Translation.java:10)
- 05-11 13:15:53.028: E/AndroidRuntime(512):   at iKA.PROJ.TestProjActivity$1.run(TestProjActivity.java:20)
- 05-11 13:15:53.028: E/AndroidRuntime(512):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
- 05-11 13:15:53.053: I/dalvikvm(512): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
- 05-11 13:15:53.053: E/dalvikvm(512): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
- 05-11 13:20:53.135: I/Process(512): Sending signal. PID: 512 SIG: 9

What do I wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to cast your `Runnable` into a `Context`.  This is not possible

I think that you want to do is

```
Translation th = new Translation(TestProjActivity.this);
```

and

```
public Translation(Context context) {
    super(context);          
}
```

Comment: and how to invoke super constructor DBHelper(),it will be undefined

Answer (score 1):

Translation constructor take Activity(Context). But Translation constructor signature take Runnable. I think this is your problem (wrong class cast from Context/Activity to Runnable).